# How detect incoming and outgoing call end state? iphone

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

I have a requirement that is the app should disappear after install and when incoming or outgoing call, soon after the call the app should prompt and display the screen.

How disappear app after installation?

How detect incoming and outgoing call?

How display screen after ending of incoming and outgoing call?

The main thing is that i am making this for personal not of app store. So please if you have any idea about then give full suggestion and ideas.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: found solution when app in background?

Comment: I used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29484246/1121497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following notification to find the call status.Add CoreTelephony.framework

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callReceived:) name:CTCallStateIncoming object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callEnded:) name:CTCallStateDisconnected object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callConnected:) name:CTCallStateConnected object:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for response. But i have a query that i will work in background and foreground and where i apply this code.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application - Use this delegate for foreground activity.   -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application - Use this delegate for background activity.

Comment: @ios: Are you able to run the app in background and able to retrieve the notifications,I also have similar requirement,could you please update this.

Comment: @Ram hi Ram ,  did you find your answer, if yes , please share.

Comment: @2003G35 would like to know: Is this working for anyone on ios9.2?

Comment: @SmokeDispenser No, it seems `CTCallCenter` and `CTCall` features aren't working at all in iOS 9.x