# how to handle the application on outgoing and incoming calls in ios phone phonegap programming?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can any one suggest me how to handle a application in iOS phonegap if any outgoing calls and incoming phone calls. Actually I m new to phone-gap based applications

Currently I m developing an application to track the location in background. If any incoming or outgoing call appears ,I need to stop my application background location tracking(incoming/outgoing call) and start the location tracking after call ends.

I have referred this link:
[How detect incoming and outgoing call end state? iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681475/how-detect-incoming-and-outgoing-call-end-state-iphone)

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(callReceived:) name:CTCallStateIncoming object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callEnded:) name:CTCallStateDisconnected object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callConnected:) name:CTCallStateConnected object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  core telephony framework and its delegate methods solved my requirement.

```
   //Initialize the plugin
  - (void)pluginInitialize
   {
   self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
   [self handleCall];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callReceived:) name:CTCallStateIncoming object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callEnded:) name:CTCallStateDisconnected object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callConnected:) name:CTCallStateConnected object:nil];
    }


 //handle calls
 -(void)handleCall
   {
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){

    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateConnected");//Background task stopped
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateDialing");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateDisconnected");//Background task started
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
        NSLog(@"call CTCallStateIncoming");
    }
    else  {
        NSLog(@"call NO");
    }
  };
 }
```

Comment: This is a native iOS solution not really a PhoneGap solution.

Comment: Yes implemented in phone-gap  using native plugin class  working fine in my phone-gap application

Comment: Hey, so you created a plugin ? can you detail a bit how you succeed to do that ?