# Is there any way to get outgoing call state in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

We have to develop an iOS app that detect incoming and outgoing call states. We are able to get incoming call state but not getting the status for outgoing calls. For making a call we have to  minimise our app, so that our app is now in background and henceforth we are not getting the background state. Following is the code to get the call states:

```
-(void)handleCall
{
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){
        if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
        {
            NSLog(@"call connected");
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
        {
            NSLog(@"dialing...");
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
        {
            NSLog(@"Current CallID : %@",call.callID);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callDisconnected" object:nil userInfo:nil];
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
        {
            NSLog(@"call incoming");
        }
    };
}
```

Help me please to detect outgoing calls.

Comment: see this once may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681475/how-detect-incoming-and-outgoing-call-end-state-iphone